# Writing a programming language

Tags: programming-languages

## Disclaimer: Yes I know this will take 3 years, at least.

I am looking forward to writing a new interpreted programming language. I have a quite solid idea of what I want in terms of dynamicness, syntax, object model, etc, etc.

Now that I have the idea, I have a few questions before I start:

1. Should I begin writing the full specification and then implement, or write them both all along?
2. I'm still doubting between C and C++. C++ would allow for more clean design and faster development while C would (maybe) ensure portability to more platforms (microprocessors?). Performance is a must.
3. Should I try to interest people for the project before the first working prototype so they can cooperate (the end product will be a liberal license anyway), or keep working alone until I have something that runs?
4. How modular should it be? I am sure that I won't immediately start working on a bytecode interpreter but something easier to implement but slower thing first, so modularity is a must in order to be able to extend later, but I guess overdoing it will hamper performance and clearity.

Comment: Why would you ever do this? If you know anything about programming language design, you know that your language will likely sink without trace, and is unlikely to improve your productivity. What's the use-case here that makes this a compelling idea?

Comment: I'd add that if you need to ask some of these questions (especially 1 and 4), you need to learn a lot of stuff before you can create a "good" language. If that is so, it pretty much doesn't matter what you do, because your first language will be terrible, and you will hate it (which is not a dig at you - it is like expecting your first novel to be very good).

Comment: @Marcin: `is unlikely to improve your productivity` Productivty is not really my goal. My goal is to learn a lot about language design (something that interests me a __lot__), and perhaps if I'm lucky create a "good" language in the run too. It's pretty unlikely I'm going to use it in a real project.

Comment: Sounds like a doctoral thesis to me; maybe investigating this at a local university would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The answers to your questions depend largely on *why* you're doing this- the primary reason.  Are you trying to create the next Ruby, or is this a learning exercise?

1. Specification:  If this is a personal project, this is not as important.  PHP gets a bad rap for having been developed "on the fly," yet many people use it every day.  A more complete spec will probably help get people involved if/when you want help.
2. If you want cross-platform and performance, C is the way to go.
3. If you want people to join in, prove something first.  Write a killer-cool application with your language and blog/talk about why your language is different/special/better.
4. Modularity of what, the language itself or the compiler?  If you want to extend the language, a good spec will help (see #1.)  The compiler should be designed with all the best practices in mind, which should help make it extensible.

I hear the [Dragon Book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers%3a_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) is good for learning to develop compilers.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your specification will be broken unless you write it hand-in-hand with the implementation.
2. If you think C++ would give you cleaner design and faster development, you should probably use it.
3. You will have difficulty getting anyone interested in a project unless there is something that runs and demonstrates what is unique about your language.
4. If you think your language will ever require a byte-code interpreter (and you do say "Performance is a must") you should investigate the capabilities of existing byte-code interpreters before you finalize your language design.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have set yourself too many goals. You say "performance is a must" but in a comment reply you say your goal is "to learn a lot about language design" and that it is "pretty unlikely" that you'll use it in a real project. New programming languages are created to solve problems; more precisely, they're created to help people express solutions to problems in better ways. Designing a language without using it seriously, intensely, continually is like writing software without any test cases: you're likely to wind up with something unusable.

If you want to try your hand at *language design*, then find a problem---one that you care about---that existing languages won't let you solve the way you want. Then do whatever you can to get a working implementation and start writing and running programs using it. You don't need a hand-crafted JIT compiler with a runtime written in highly bummed assembly code. If you target the JVM or .NET, you get a very high-performance GC, scalable threading system, libraries, and lots of other good stuff for free, even if it interferes with that awesome idea you had for `______`.

On the other hand, if you just want to make something run fast, don't try to design a language at the same time. Just find one that you like, learn about implementation strategies, and see if you can do better.